# LastInsertId de Mysqli para PDO

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

Tenho uma página de inserção, assim que clico em inserir nova acomodação, o sistema deve inserir uns dados prontos, porém na mesma página eu preciso recuperar o último id, para que assim eu possa completar as outras informações do formulário, como se eu estivesse editando a informação.

Em `mysqli` eu consegui, mais preciso transformar para PDO, e estou tendo dificuldades, segue abaixo o código.

```
$imagem="produto.png";

$insert=mysqli_query($con,"insert into tbl_acomodacoes (acomodacao_imagem, acomodacao_situacao) values ('$imagem','0')");

$sql_last=mysqli_query($con,"select LAST_INSERT_ID(acomodacao_id) as last from tbl_acomodacoes order by acomodacao_id desc limit 0,1");

$rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_last);

$acomodacao_id=intval($rw['last']);

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tbl_acomodacoes where acomodacao_id='$acomodacao_id' limit 0,1");

$count=mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if ($count==0){

    //header("location: acomodacao.php");

    //exit;

}

$rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

$titulo=$rw['acomodacao_titulo'];

$slug=$rw['acomodacao_slug'];

$link=$rw['acomodacao_link'];

$texto=$rw['acomodacao_texto'];

$quantidade=$rw['acomodacao_quantidade'];

$imagem=$rw['acomodacao_imagem'];

$situacao=intval($rw['acomodacao_situacao']);
```

Comment: Caro Samuel, por que precisa disto em PDO? O que tem de mal com o mysqli?

Answer (score 1):

Usando PDO, o código ficaria assim:

```
$imagem = "produto.png";

$insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_acomodacoes(acomodacao_imagem, acomodacao_situacao) VALUES(?,?);");
$sonuc = $insert->execute([$imagem , '0']);
$last_id = $con->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Isso é só parte do que ele fez e realmente não tem sentido em trocar o mysqli por PDO, tem gente que acredita que os códigos são portaveis entre diferentes bancos, o que não passa de um mito inventado por pessoas que sabiam pouco. Não tem porque trocar algo bom por algo mais ou menos, sim, na pratica PDO é um pouquinho pior que o mysqli, pode até ter parametros nomeados, mas o processo é do lado do PHP, enquanto do mysqli é do lado do servidor mysql e também o mysqli suporta mysqlnd, que para quem entende sabe que isto ajuda com diversas coisas relacionadas.

Comment: Pois é Guilherme, concordo que se estiver funcionando com o MySQLi não compensa trocar. Só postei a resposta para atender a pergunta do Samuel. E outra, dependendo de como estiver o sistema dele, é bem árdua a manutenção para trocar o driver de conexão na aplicação toda... Obrigado!

Comment: Tem pergunta que nem deveriam ter resposta, ainda mais se responde somente a metade e pior ainda se a pergunta é um "helpdesk" (do tipo "faça pra mim"), eu vejo que o site deveria ensinar as APIs mencionadas e explicar como se aprofundar, mas em todo canto vejo respostas como "tente isto", que acabam servindo mais como Ctrl+C. Essa pergunta no máximo deveria ser comentada e deveria ser fechada, pq a troca de ambas APIs não apresenta nenhum propósito, só é um pedido de "faça pra mim"

Comment: @RodrigoTognin obrigado pela ajuda !!!